# Sort a dataframe with an external dataframe with identical values in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes

```
> sel
    rank x1 x2 x3  sel
1      1  0  0  0 TRUE
101  101  0 10  0 TRUE
201  201  0 20  0 TRUE
301  301  0 30  0 TRUE
401  401  0 40  0 TRUE
501  501  0 50  0 TRUE
601  601  0 60  0 TRUE
701  701  0 70  0 TRUE
801  801  0 80  0 TRUE
901  901  0 90  0 TRUE
```

and

```
rank_order_1000$rank
   [1]      1  10001  20001  30001  40001  50001  60001  70001  80001  90001 100001 110001 120001
  [14] 130001 140001 150001 160001 170001 180001 190001 200001 210001 220001 230001 240001 250001
  [27] 260001 270001 280001 290001 300001 310001 320001 330001 340001 350001 360001 370001 380001
```

The **rank** column of the **sel** contains the same values as the **rank_order_1000$rank** dataframe. I'd like to sort the **sel** dataframe based on the order of the **rank_order_1000$rank** dataframe. I tried many options seen on Stack Overflow, but none of them give me the output that I want. Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
sel[match(sel$rank, rank_order_1000$rank), ]
```

---

Here's using a small reproducible example :

```
sel <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], rank = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 5))
sel
#  x rank
#1 a    2
#2 b    3
#3 c    1
#4 d    4
#5 e    5
rank_order_1000 <-  data.frame(rank  = c(4, 3, 1, 2, 5))
rank_order_1000
#  rank
#1    4
#2    3
#3    1
#4    2
#5    5

sel[match(sel$rank, rank_order_1000$rank), ]

#  x rank
#4 d    4
#2 b    3
#3 c    1
#1 a    2
#5 e    5
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was wasting time with the "order" function, and "arrange" function from dplyr. Didn't know about "match"